# Custom Attributes Migration from .Net Framework to .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-4.8

I have this code

```
public class ExcludeFromProdAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var lang = filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString().ToLower();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang) || (lang != "eng" && lang != "fra"))
            lang = "eng";

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["org-environment"].ToUpper() == "PROD")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"lang", lang },
                    {"controller", "Checkout"},
                    {"action", "Error"},
                    {"errorcode", "Cardinal" }
                }

                );
        }
    }
}
```

Which I'd like to convert to .Net Core.  Unfortunately, I do not have the time to re-write the entire application, and due to some organizational constraints - this needs to move to .Net core.

I looked up AuthorizationContext, and seems like the object I need to use is "AuthorizationHandlerContext" however it renders even the method signature invalid.

Some help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar implementation for asp.net core:

```cs
public class ExcludeFromProdAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ExcludeFromProdAttribute(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var lang = context.RouteData.Values["lang"]?.ToString()?.ToLower();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang) || (lang != "eng" && lang != "fra"))
            lang = "eng";

        if (_configuration.GetValue<string>("org-environment").Equals("prod", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"lang", lang },
                    {"controller", "Checkout"},
                    {"action", "Error"},
                    {"errorcode", "Cardinal" }
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```